# How to connect two dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate a "linked" drop down menu by using someone else's code. But for some reason the code isn't executing. I can select the first drop down but it does nothing to the second one.

I use JFiddle and paste code into relevant sections and it worked!

So I am a little lost.

Thank you for your advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <style type="text/css">
            .subcat option {
                display: none;
            }
            .subcat option.label {
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToNewPage()
  {
    var url = document.getElementById('store').value;
    console.log(url);
    if(url != 'none') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    
    var $cat = $("#state"),
        $subcat = $(".subcat");
    
    $cat.on("change",function(){
        var _rel = $(this).val();
        $subcat.find("option").attr("style","");
        $subcat.val("");
        if(!_rel) return $subcat.prop("disabled",true);
        $subcat.find("[rel="+_rel+"]").show();
        $subcat.prop("disabled",false);
    });
    
});
</script>
<form id="formname" name="Sate-Store">
    
                    <select name="state" id="state">
                        <option value="">Select state</option>
                        <option value="ma">MA</option>
                        <option value="me">ME</option>
                        <option value="nh">NH</option>
                    </select>
                    <select disabled="disabled" class="subcat" id="store" name="store">
                        <option value>Select a store</option>
                        <!-- MA -->
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_1">MA Store 1</option>
            <option rel="ma" value="http://www.google.com">MA Store 2</option>
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_3">MA Store 3</option>
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_4">MA Store 4</option>
                        <option rel="ma" value="ma_store_5">MA Store 5</option>
                        <!-- ME -->
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_1">ME Store 1</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_2">ME Store 2</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_3">ME Store 3</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_4">ME Store 4</option>
                        <option rel="me" value="me_store_5">ME Store 5</option>
                        <!-- MH -->
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_1">NH Store 1</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_2">NH Store 2</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_3">NH Store 3</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_4">NH Store 4</option>
                        <option rel="nh" value="nh_store_5">NH Store 5</option>
                    </select>
          <input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage()" />

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Tried using JFiddle - it worked

Comment: I don't understand why you put your code out side of the body tag.  You should keep your style before the </head> tag and js code before the </body> tag and all other html code after <body> tag. then your code will be work

Comment: My bad copying error. Still doesn't work with the body tag in the right place.

Comment: What is your expectation? When I just copy your code and paste it in the editor it working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code. It works on JSFiddle but does not work in plain HTML. The problem is `jquery.js` failed to load.

[image: reason]

you can change that library from

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js
```

to

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js
```